# Click CardView to open new activity

Tags: android, cardview

How to open new Activity by clicking [cardview]  I am beginner and i have no idea of using [CardView] as a button. Help me i need example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you added `CardView` in xml

```
CardView cardView=findViewById(R.id.cardView);
     cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourActivityName.class);
                startActivtiy(intent);
            }
        });
```

add above code in your `onCreate` method